# How to add Textbox and buttons to gmail messages and get the responce from them

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, gmail

I want to add two buttons to my gmail messages YES and NO if we pressed on YES then show one Textbox and a submit button .and if we press on submit button the value od the textbox must be saved. how can i achieve that . Am sorry for my bad language

Comment: What response? Send back to your email or save to web server?

Comment: it may be a number in the textbox like number of persons ,and it save to a web server . can we do that ? @Samuel Tulach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this simply using google form. Just follow the steps below
1) Go to google forms create a new form as you like
2) then click on send form choose send via email option mention the to email address, subject and message. Don't forget to check Include form in email option.
Then click on send button.
When the recipient receive this email that would contain an embedded google form. The responses of google form can be retrieve via email or it can be save into a linked excel file on google drive.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to your problem is to put Links in your E-Mail, which redirect the user to a website of yours. If he presses no, then your website (where the user was redirected from the no-button) can just save the response and close the tab again. If the user presses yes, the user can enter the information in the textbox (in your website from the link from the yes-button) and save it on your website after the user submitted it.

That's usually the practice how such things work. Another example for this is unsubscribing from newsletters. There you also get redirected to the website of the sender of the newsletter and may enter your e-mail and the reasons why you unsubscribe.

Hope I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

> it may be a number in the textbox like number of persons ,and it save
>   to a web server . can we do that ?

In pure e-mail based on HTML and JavaScript? No. You can't. You need PHP to send response to server and this is not allowed in e-mails and with JavaScript is basically impossible to do it. next problem is, that you cant use `iframe` or something like this, because Gmail and other e-mail clients don't allow it.

But how?
You can create good looking button with HTML/CSS and on it add link to answer to your page, where you can easily process user data. If you haven't got many programming skills you can use [Google Forms](https://www.google.cz/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiKkYXNu87SAhVIIpoKHUNjDGYQFggzMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.google.com%2Fforms%2F&usg=AFQjCNGd9jkokLP-5hiQ7x2zWitYDeK0TQ&sig2=wCMAdGzK3bjEsMeSgL_lew). Google Forms is easy to use for any user and you can create your own form without having server, because all data will save at google for free
+ it have [API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/quickstart/forms).

Plus Google Forms have function for sending forms via e-mail!
[image: sorry for czech]

(Sorry for Czech in image.)

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much sir.that worked perfectly..thank you for your valuable  time .